# CSS page height 100vh not working

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to set the body and html to 100vh / 100% of my browser which works fine but once I get content that's longer than the original page it stops working with the background colors, which I can't make any sense of. I checked many posts on stackoverflow but can't seem to find the trick.

Here is a screen of my page, I made the background red for better visibility:
[image: screen of the problem]

[image: the problkem div in blue]

My code is inside an Angular 2 application with many different Sass files, but here is the code that sets up the menu/content area and wrappers.

```
@import "../assets/sass/variables";


body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

body, .wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.main-content-area {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}


.dont-break-out {
  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  /* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
  word-break: break-word;

  /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}


@media (min-width: 576px) {

  .main-content-area {
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
  }

}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .container {
    width: 718px;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .main-content-area {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
  }

  .container {
    width: 792px;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

  .container {
    width: 1000px;
  }

}
@media (min-width: 1400px) {

  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }

}
```

I hope anyone had a similar issue before. Note that my content area is continuing after the red background and menu background. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: You mean the white background of your elements, e.g. "Students"? Are you using any CSS frameworks like bootstrap?

Comment: Sorry maybe i wasn't very clear in my initial post, I added another picture with the problem in blue. its the content wrapper of the main box that is now blue.

Comment: Looks like your content is exceeding the height of your screen, so you'd probably be better off styling with `min-height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100vh`.

Comment: @JonUleis That seemed to be the problem. thanks for the pointer.